# div float left and bottom bar

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this layout

```
 _______________________
|                       |
|        Table 1        |
|_______________________|
 _______________________
|                       |
|        Table 2        | 
|_______________________|  ___________________
                          |                   |
                          |    bottom bar     |
                          |___________________|
```

The bottom bar has to always stay at the bottom of the page just to the right of the tables.

This is what I have so far.

I have this html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tables">
        <div id="table1" class="box">
            <table><tr><td>table 1</td></tr></table>
        </div>
        <div id="table2" class="box">
            <table><tr><td>table 2</td></tr></table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottombar box"> bottom bar</div>
</div>
```

and this for css

```
.container{ height: 1000px}
.tables{float: left}
.box{border: 1px solid #ddd; height:150px; width: 100px;}
.bottombar{float: left; position: fixed; bottom: 10px;}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJw5z/) link

The problem is that the bottom bar overlaps with the tables but it has to stay to the right of the tables. If I remove position fixed, the bottom bar stays to the right of the tables but is no longer attached to the bottom. Can any one guide me to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: What was your comment again?  I think it got deleted.

Comment: Is this for a fixed or fluid layout?

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML in any way?

Comment: @wex yeah. I can change the html but I would prefer to keep a div for container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the value of a margin using a percent value is relative to the containing element. To achieve your desired effect, you just need to make some minor changes to your code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tables">
        <div id="table1" class="box">
            <table><tr><td>table 1</td></tr></table>
        </div>
        <div id="table2" class="box">
            <table><tr><td>table 2</td></tr></table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottombar"><div class="box">bottom bar</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tables { float: left; }
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px; 
    border: 1px solid #ddd; }
.bottombar{
    float: left;
    clear: both; }
.bottombar .box { margin: 0 0 0 100%; }
```

*You might want to add `.container { overflow: hidden; }` to clear your floats.*

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/9bZDx/

Edit:

To get it to stick at the bottom of the page, just add the following to `.bottombar`:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/9bZDx/3/

Comment: Thanks Wex; but the bottombar does not seem to stay at the bottom with scrolling .

Comment: Oh, whoops - didn't understand that part of the question. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if this will help, but I enclosed everything in a table: http://jsfiddle.net/eJw5z/2/

Comment: I want to use css floats. I don't want to use table for container. But this solution definitely helps.

Comment: Do you want the bottom bar to be just to the right of the tables or can it be on the right side of the page?

Comment: I do want it to be just to the right of the tables but I'm curious to see what it looks like if it can be set to the right side of the page.

Comment: Actually, I ended up using the table solution but if you do come across a div float solution, please update your answer.

Comment: You don't have to accept the answer until you feel like it's been answered to your liking.

Comment: Ok I will!  I am trying to find one out, don't worry.

Comment: @Wex this answer works for me for now. If there is a better answer, I can always change.

Answer (score 0):

(1)Try assigning float: right; to the bottom bar css and you can use margins to position it correctly.

(2)You could create 2 additional divs within bottom bar and make them right & left.

Its kind of hard to tell what you want you true end result to be, but that should get you further down the road to figuring it out :D

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, setting `left: 102px;` to `.bottombar` should solve your problem. Since you are setting a specific width on the tables, you can very easy set a left position from which to offset.

That said, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like it might be related to a [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). I would recommend looking into if that will solve your problem.

Comment: The width of the tables aren't fixed. I have them set in the question just to give them some width.

Comment: @ProfessorChaos Is the height of the bottombar static?